# How to remove inactive printers from print service on android?

Tags: android, android-studio

In the requirement the list of available printers changes quite often. However, I have not been able to find a way of removing the non-existing printers (i.e. printers that were available at some point). These printers appear inactive on my test devices.

I can see inactive printers in PrinterDiscoverySession's onStartPrinterDiscovery() and onValidatePrinters() methods but do not know how to remove them. Calling session's addPrinters() with existing printers or removePrinters() with non-existing ones does not help.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in Advance.